# Looking for information about programming QR codes

Tags: php, qr-code

I am looking for 2 pieces of information about building QR codes, but Google is failing me:

1. (Most important) Information about the different message formats; like MEBKM, SMSTO, TEL, GEO, WIFI, etc. i.e. Others not listed and how they are formatted (e.g. `"MEBKM:TITLE:{$title};URL:{$url};;"`).
2. How to build them. Wikipedia has a little info, but not enough. (Currently I am using Google, but I want a little more power)

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know how useful this will be (or if you've already seen this and the resources it links to) but the [zxing project](https://code.google.com/p/zxing/) has a [page about contents of 2D barcodes](https://code.google.com/p/zxing/wiki/BarcodeContents)

Answer (score 0):

> ### **Phone**
>
> tel: {telephone number}
>
> You can Barcode that contains a phone number
> in the format above
>
> ### **SMS**
>
> smsto: {telephone number}: {text}
>
> Phone number in the format above, you can Barcode that contains the
> text (Example) smsto: 123456: test
>
> ### **WIFI**
>
> WIFI: S: {SSID}; P: {password}; T: {type}
>
> SSID in the above format, password, you can Barcode that contains the
> type (WEP/WAP/OPEN) It becomes OPEN If you do not specify the type of
> (Example) WIFI: S: TenChars; P: 0123456789; T: WEP ;;
>
> ### **Geo-location**
>
> geo: {latitude}, {longitude}
>
> Barcode can containing latitude and longitude in the form of the k
> geo:-20.33,132.3344
>
> ### **Contact information:**
>
> **MECARD**
>
> MECARD: N: {name}; ORG: {belong}; TEL: {telephone number}; EMAIL:
> {email address}; ADR: {address}; NOTE: {memo}
>
> In the above format, name, affiliation, phone number, e-mail address,
> address, you can Barcode that includes a note
>
> **vCard**
>
> BEGIN:VCARD VERSION:3.0 N: {name} ORG: {belong} TITLE: {title} TEL:
> {telephone number} URL:{URL} EMAIL: {email address} ADR: {Address}
> NOTE: {memo} END:VCARD NOTE:test memo
>
> In the above format, name, affiliation, title, phone number, URL,
> e-mail address, address, you can Barcode that includes a note
>
> ### **Calendar event**
>
> **VEVENT**
>
> BEGIN:VEVENT SUMMARY: {Overview} DTSTART: {Start Time} DTEND: {End
> Time} LOCATION: {location} DESCRIPTION: {Details} END:VEVENT
>
> In the above format, summary, start time, end time, location, you can
> Barcode that contains the details

Usage:
with "segno":
https://segno.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

```
import segno

phone_number = '+99988666555'
qr= segno.make(f'tel:{phone_number}')
qr.save('QR_image.png')
```

or with "qrcode":
https://pypi.org/project/qrcode/

```
import qrcode
    
phone_number = '+99988666555'
text = 'Some text'
qr= qrcode.make(f'smsto: {phone_number}: {text}')
qr.save('QR_image.png')
```